# How to query jsonb field type

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

```
DailyCount.create(data: [
{product_id: 1, favorite_count: 5, email_count: 10}, { product_id: 3, favorite_count: 3, email_count: 1}])
```

```
DailyCount.create(data: [
{product_id: 2, favorite_count: 10, email_count: 5}, { product_id: 1, favorite_count: 0, email_count: 1}])
```

DailyCount keeps record of daily data so these data are of two consecutive days.

Expected Result:

```
Top 3 favorite products(id, total_favorite_count, total_email_count, last_favorite_date, last_email_date)
```

So,

```
result = [{product_id: 2, total_favorite_count: 10, total_email_count: 5, last_favorite_date: second_record_created_at_date, last_email_date: second_record_created_at_date},  { product_id: 1, total_favorite_count: 5, total_email_count: 11, last_favorite_date: first_record_created_at_date, last_email_date: second_record_created_at_date}, {third_record....} ]
```

How can I achieve this? Please help me!

PS: I have got top 3 products but only ids, total_favorite_count and total_email_count by mapping the data column and using #group_by. I can get the date data too, but I don't think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: No its definitely not the best way to approach the problem. Why are you using a JSONB column in the first place instead of for example a materialized view? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html

Comment: Thank you, but users can apply date range to the records and materialized view is dependent on cache.